# Concatenate object text values with for loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, text

I'm trying to take an array of names and add them to a single variable using a `for` loop then display it to the console.

```
var list = "";
var names = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

for(i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    list = list.concat(names[i].firstChild);
}

console.log(list);
```

But it outputs a long list of:

```
[object Text][object Text][object Text][object Text][object Text][object Text][object Text]
```

Note:
 `console.log(names[22].firstChild)` outputs `"Richard"` in the console just fine. I'm just having problems concatenating them to the variable `list`.

The code of the  is as follows.

```
<h3 style="color:white; font-weight:300;" class="staff">
  Richard Smith<br>
  <span style="font-size:14px;">Data Analyst</span>
</h3>
```

That is why I used `.firstChild`. If I use `.innerText` it returns both the name and the `<span>` that follows it.

Comment: try to use not `firstChild` but `innerText`

Comment: @jfriend00 Because `list` is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `names[i].firstChild` attribute references a text node that contains the value you would like to get at.

Instead of accessing the `firstChild` attribute, use `innerHTML` or `innerText` to get a string rather than a text node.

I added a space in between each name as well.

```js
var list = "";
var names = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  list = list.concat(names[i].innerHTML.split('<br>')[0] + ' ');
}

console.log(list);
```

```html
<h3 style="color:white; font-weight:300;" class="staff">
  Richard Smith<br>
  <span style="font-size:14px;">Data Analyst</span>
</h3>
```

**EDIT:**

Updated answer after OP posted HTML.

With the HTML structure you are using, the `innerText` attribute will retrieve the job title as well.

If all of your `<h3>` tags are formatted the same way, you can get the `innerHTML`, then split the string at the `<br>`, then take the first half that contains the name and append it to your list.

Comment: the trick is to use innerText. It seems + ' ' isn't necessary (also, it is not the same as the code in the question. Extra spaces.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `nodeValue`

```
var list = "";
var names = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

for(i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    list = list.concat(names[i].firstChild.nodeValue + ' ');
}

console.log(list);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdL7rbud/)